# Answering a purely JavaScript question with jQuery (Needs more jQuery)

Tags: discussion, tags, answers

I saw this answer to a JavaScript question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30896696/2117156

Admittedly the question looks like it's not going to last long, however the answer by Ryan Gittens basically says "You need to do X, however this jQuery code will help: [insert jQuery code]".

I down-voted and commented on it, however he didn't take too kindly to it.

How should this situation be handled? I realise my reply to "can't you read?" could have been better, but I was annoyed by it and couldn't help myself.